# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un menú con varias matrices y elegir dos?

Tags: java, matrices, netbeans-8.2

necesito hacer un ejercicio donde tengo 4 matrices de 3x3 con números aleatorios y posteriormente escoger 2 de las 4 matrices para sumarlas. Es decir, voy a hacer cuatro matrices y luego voy a hacer que el usuario escoja dos matrices y a esas dos matrices sumarlas.

Mi error principal es en la elección de la matriz con la que el usuario desea trabajar, realmente tengo varias dudas con respecto a esa parte. Intenté con un switch dándole a `matrizElegida1` y `matrizElegida2` los valores de una matriz ya generada dependiendo de la respuesta del usuario, por ejemplo: `matrizElegida1[][] = matriz1[filas][columnas];` pero no funciona...

```
//Inicializo las variables
    int[][] matriz1 = new int[3][3];
    int[][] matrizElegida1 = new int[3][3];
    int[][] matrizElegida2 = new int[3][3];
    int[][] matrizSuma = new int[3][3];
    int opcion1;
    int opcion2;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Genero las cuatro matrices
    System.out.print("Matriz 1");
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
            matriz1[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            System.out.print(matriz1[filas][columnas] + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\nMatriz 2");
    int[][] matriz2 = new int[3][3];
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
            matriz2[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            System.out.print(matriz2[filas][columnas] + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\nMatriz 3");
    int[][] matriz3 = new int[3][3];
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
            matriz3[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            System.out.print(matriz3[filas][columnas] + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\nMatriz 4");
    int[][] matriz4 = new int[3][3];
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
            matriz4[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            System.out.print(matriz4[filas][columnas] + " ");
        }
    }

    //Hago un menú con opciones
    System.out.println("\n1. Matriz 1");
    System.out.println("2. Matriz 2");
    System.out.println("3. Matriz 3");
    System.out.println("4. Matriz 4");
    System.out.println("Elija la primera de las matrices con la que desea trabajar: ");
    opcion1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Has elegido la matriz " + opcion1);

    //Utilizo un switch para ver las posibilidades de respuesta.
    switch (opcion1) {
        case 1:
            matrizElegida1[][] = matriz1[filas][columnas];
        case 2:
            matrizElegida1[][] = matriz2[filas][columnas];
        case 3:
            matrizElegida1[][] = matriz3[filas][columnas];
        case 4:
            matrizElegida1[][] = matriz4[filas][columnas];
    }

    System.out.println("\n1. Matriz 1");
    System.out.println("2. Matriz 2");
    System.out.println("3. Matriz 3");
    System.out.println("4. Matriz 4");
    System.out.println("Elija la segunda de las matrices con la que desea trabajar: ");
    opcion2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Has elegido la matriz " + opcion2);
    switch (opcion2) {
        case 1:
            matrizElegida2[][] = matriz1[filas][columnas];
        case 2:
            matrizElegida2[][] = matriz2[filas][columnas];
        case 3:
            matrizElegida2[][] = matriz3[filas][columnas];
        case 4:
            matrizElegida2[][] = matriz4[filas][columnas];
    }

    //Sumo la matriz elegida 1 y la matriz elegida 2 y guardo los resultados en una nueva matriz llamada matrizSuma
    System.out.print("\nLa matriz resultante de la suma es: ");
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
            matrizSuma[filas][columnas] = matrizElegida1[filas][columnas] + matrizElegida2[filas][columnas];
            System.out.print(matrizSuma[filas][columnas] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bueno, lo primero que veo es que en los *cases*, a los que les falta su repectivo `break`, las asignaciónes deberían ser `matrizElegida1 = matriz1;`, etc... sin `[][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciona el comentario de @Omi, el problema esta en tu switch, ademas de que faltan los breaks, las asignaciones estan incorrectas, solo debes cambiarlo por el siguiente codigo, donde comantare los cambios realizados y el porque:

```
switch (opcion1) {
        case 1:

            /*matrizElegida1[][] = matriz1[filas][columnas];
            Las llaves son innecesarias, ya que las variables ya estan declaradas como                            matrices.
Ademas de esto los indices en matriz1[filas][columnas] no son necesarios, ya que al colocar indices estas tratando de asignar el valor de matrizElegida1 a un solo elemento de la matriz.*/

            matriculaElegida1=matriz1;
// Al realizar los cambios a la asignacion queda como la ves en la linea anterior.
            break;  //Nunca olvides colocar breaks, al final de cada caso
        case 2:
            matrizElegida1 = matriz2;
            break;  //Nunca olvides colocar breaks, al final de cada caso
        case 3:
            matrizElegida1 = matriz3;
            break;  //Nunca olvides colocar breaks, al final de cada caso
        case 4:
            matrizElegida1 = matriz4;
            break;  //Nunca olvides colocar breaks, al final de cada caso
    }
```

Realiza los mismos cambios en el switch de opcion 2 y deberia funcionar.

Comment: ¡Gracias, me ha servido!